# How to pass command-line argument from within a java program?

Tags: java, command-line, parameter-passing

I want to use WordNet and its packages for which I am using wn.exe and need to pass "-n#" argument to it. How do I do it from within my java code which is running on the computer.

***Edit: I have a running a java program and from within that program, I need to pass "-n#" as argument to a native process wn.exe and I need to know to how do I do that.*

PS If it is something stupid, I really regret it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). You can set arguments with `command(...)`.

`Runtime.exec()` also works, but ProcessBuilder is better.

Comment: Thanks. But, what do I exactly send as the parameter when I call the ProcessBuilder.command(...)

Comment: The first argument to command() is the name of the executable, the rest are the arguments you want to pass to it. In your case something like `command("C:\\Programs\\WordNet.exe", "-n#")`. The link above is for you so that you can read the documentation where everything is explained.

Answer (score 0):

Here example how to work with Process:

```
public BufferedReader runCommand(String command) throws IOException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    input.close();
    return input;
}
```